Power Number of Impellers in non-Newtonian fluids
I have been working on a project involving mixing a non-Newtonian fluid.
To begin with, the fluid exhibits a shear-thinning behaviour that follows the power law:
$$\tau = K \dot{\gamma}^n$$
As for the impeller, it is known that, in order to determine the mechanical power delivered to the fluid, we need the power number: $$N_p = P/\rho.N^3.D^5$$
with P being the mechanical power, N the rotation speed of the impeller (RPM), D the diameter of the impeller (m) and $\rho$ the density of the fluid.
For that matter, we need to calculate the Reynolds number $R_e$, and then, determine the power number $N_p$ using the graphs that describe their relationship: 
Now, the problem resides in the fact that the Reynolds number $R_e$ , has a different formula than that usually used for such curves, seeing that it no longer has a constant viscosity: $$R_e = D^2.N.\rho / \mu $$
This means that these curves can no longer give us correct results.
Thus, we need some general formula, which there is available in literature. It goes like this : $$N_p = K.(R_e)^c.(F_r)^b $$
K, b and c are empirical constants that depend on the impeller geometry and design, as well as its interaction with the fluid.
The issue is that I couldn't find any value of these constants in literature and research papers, and the fact that they are empirical makes it even harder because right then, I'd have to conduct experiments on the fluid and the impeller, which I can't.
Therefore, I want to know if my reasoning concerning the invalidity of the $N_p = f(R_e)$ curves in the case of non-Newtonian fluids, and if there are any resources concerning the constants K, b and c .

The generalization of your non-Newtonian equation for 1D shear deformation is expressed in terms of the second invariant of the rate of deformation tensor using the generalized Newtonian fluid equation.

That is how I find it pretty much everywhere @ChetMiller . Is it wrong in any way ? I'd love to know.
